# ASP Calendar PostBack & DayRender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two calendars which act as control parameters for an `SqlDataSource`; `fromDateCal` and `toDateCal`. Both calendars have their own respective `DayRender` events which limits the dates available on each.

The calendars are set up as follows:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="fromDateCal" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999"
        CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
        ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px" onDayRender="fromDateCal_DayRender">
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
    <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CEDEF4" BorderColor="#7BA7E1" BorderWidth="2" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#2966B8" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC99" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
</asp:Calendar>

<asp:Calendar ID="toDateCal" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999"
        CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
        ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px" OnDayRender="fromDateCal_DayRender">
    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
    <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CEDEF4" BorderColor="#7BA7E1" BorderWidth="2" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#2966B8" />
    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC99" />
    <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
</asp:Calendar>
```

The respective DayRender events are:

```
protected void fromDateCal_DayRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date > toDateCal.SelectedDate.AddDays(-1))
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.CssClass = "disabledDate";
    }
}

protected void toDateCal_DayRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date > DateTime.Now || e.Day.Date < fromDateCal.SelectedDate.AddDays(1))
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.CssClass = "disabledDate";
    }
}
```

The restrictions that are set are;

- `fromDateCal` cannot be greater than or equal to the `toDateCal.SelectedDate`
- `toDateCal` cannot be greater than `DateTime.Now` and cannot be less than or equal to the `fromDateCal.SelectedDate`.

When the page loads, these restrictions are applied and everything appears and works great. However, when a date is selected on either calendar the `DayRender` event is not executed immediately. I find that you have to select the same date again from the same calendar for the restrictions to update on both.

Is there any way of solving this and getting the `DayRender` to execute on the first `PostBack`? I have exhausted my limited knowledge of ASP.Net and am now asking for help.

Thanks.